# How to convert a NSString to AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer

Tags: swift

I am working on a mixed project of swift and objective-c.
I need to use a function like this.

`+ (nullable NSString *)funcName:(NSString **)param;`

In swift,the param becomes `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer` type.

Tried code like this

```
let str : NSString = ""
let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: str.utf8String)
let unsafe = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>.init(pointer)
let str = funcName(str.utf8String)
```

But it results in crash because the pointer I sent in is pointing to nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
let str : NSString = ""
let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: str.utf8String)
```

is already undefined behavior: You are creating a mutable pointer referencing the same memory as the (immutable) `str.utf8String`.

Actually it is much simpler: You can pass the address of an optional `NSString` as inout argument with `&`.

```
var param: NSString?
let result = YourObjCClass.funcName(&param)
```

The compiler automatically does the necessary conversion. There is seldom a need to create an `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer` explicitly.